# Cast to derived class in base class constructor Python

Tags: python, inheritance, derived-class, base-class

I have a base class and a derived class. I want to be able to cast the base class to derived class in the constructor of base class, using one of the arguments passed. Elucidated below:

```
Class A(object):
   def ___init___(self, arg1, arg2  ..., shouldBeDerivedClass):
      if shouldBeDerivedClass:
         #Cast this object to Derived Class B and Call constructor of derived class
      else:
         #Continue constructing base class object

Class B(A):
   __init__(self, some args):
      #Should reach here
```

How can I achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: `__init__` is not a constructor, it is an *initializer*. It's too late by then. But *why* should the base-class constructor return a derived class, based on an argument? Why don't you just *use the derived class constructor?*

Comment: Better to use a factory function that returns an instance of the appropriate class.

Comment: Not `Class`. It will be `class`.

Comment: +1 for factory pattern, see an example [here](http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Factory.html).

Comment: I vote for the factory function too. However, there is a horrible hack: `self.__class__ = B`. Considered awful, but if you want to have fun, go for it. You can add `B.__init__(self, *args)` afterwords.